Boolean modifier problem
I'm struggling to integrate a logo using the boolean modifier on the top of a bottle cap.
I have two problem, the first is I don't know how to properly apply the bevel modifier on the edges of the integrated logo (after the boolean modifier was applied) and the second problem is like you'll see in the picture the material is messed up because of the boolean effect, it's clear that I'm doing something wrong in my "building order" so, how I can fix this ?



on the 4th picture I was able to apply a bevel modifier (using the weight option) but in this case I used a basic cylinder without any modifier applied to it :


You should delete the top cap, grid fill it and draw the logo there. Booleans are terrible for topology

what do you mean by "draw the logo" ? sculpting ?

I added the grid fill like you adviced me to do and I'm getting closer to the desired result but now I have these issues  : https://ibb.co/B6nJc3M

The “material being messed up” is actually because of the bevel not being there for the smooth shading to work with. See this documentation for more information. As for the bevel not applying to the Boolean geometry, modifiers are executed in top down order, so if you move the bevel modifier to be below the Boolean modifier, it should apply to the Boolean geometry as well. Note that you may need to change some settings of how the bevel deals with corners and overlap to get it to look right.

I added a grid fill, I'm getting closer to the desired result but now I have these issues : ibb.co/B6nJc3M

That's technically a separate question, but try double checking that the normals on the logo stamp object are facing the right way (in edit mode with it all selected, Mesh -> Normals -> Recalculate Outside). Lots of similar questions on here with beveling if you need more info. If that doesn't work, ask a new one.
